# How can I avoid escape chars in inserted binary string with Elixir/Ecto/Postgrex?

Tags: string, postgresql, base64, elixir, ecto

I'm new to elixir/ecto and I don't understand why my `error_data` field (defined as `:binary` in schema) gets inserted slash-escaped in my postgresql column:

```
params = %{error_data: "eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiSW52YWxpZCB0b2tlbiIsImNhdXNlIjpbXSwiZXJyb3IiOiJub3RfZm91bmQiLCJzdGF0dXMiOjQwMX0="}

cast(%{}, params, [:error_data])
|> change(%{error_data: Base.decode64!(params.error_data)})
|> Ecto.Repo.insert()
```

Following @smathy insight, I've put an `IO.puts(get_change(changeset, :error_data)` between `change` and `insert` calls. It shows the data has beed decoded and is not slash escaped before insertion. But the next line showing Ecto query is escaped... Check my app's output:

```
[info] Creating error for 1 on channel 1
{"message":"Invalid token","cause":[],"error":"not_found","status":401}
[debug] QUERY OK db=0.5ms
INSERT INTO "errors" ("code","error","error_message","http_status","id","channel_id","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8) RETURNING "id" ["error-03", "{\"message\":\"Invalid token\",\"cause\":[],\"error\":\"not_found\",\"status\":401}", "Invalid token", 401, 1, 1, ~N[2021-02-16 12:24:58], ~N[2021-02-16 12:24:58]]
```

Then check these DB queries out: the first is for the code inserted error. The last is from a manually inserted not-escaped error:

```
dev=# SELECT error FROM errors ORDER BY updated_at DESC limit 1;
                                         error                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 "{\"message\":\"Invalid token\",\"cause\":[],\"error\":\"not_found\",\"status\":401}"
(1 row)

dev=# SELECT error FROM errors ORDER BY updated_at ASC limit 1;
        error        
---------------------
 {"eita": "deu pau"}
(1 row)
```

How can I avoid that escape and insert the plain decoded (`{"message":"Invalid token","cause":[],"error":"not_found","status":401}`) content?
If I could use ecto fragments in insertion, I'd have told the DB to decode the base64 string... I didn't find how to do that either... any help?

I wonder it there is any environment configuration that affects ECTO in order to log it's queries and ends up string casting/escaping the `error_data` binary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not really there, they're just being displayed by whatever tool you're using to print out that value because that tool uses `"`s as the string delimiter, and therefore escapes them to avoid ambiguity.

Same thing happens in an `iex` session, if you actually print out the value then it comes out as you're expecting because when you output a string it won't include the delimiters:

```
iex(6)> Base.decode64! "eyJtZXNzYWdlIjoiSW52YWxpZCB0b2tlbiIsImNhdXNlIjpbXSwiZXJyb3IiOiJub3RfZm91bmQiLCJzdGF0dXMiOjQwMX0="
"{\"message\":\"Invalid token\",\"cause\":[],\"error\":\"not_found\",\"status\":401}"
iex(7)> IO.puts v
{"message":"Invalid token","cause":[],"error":"not_found","status":401}
:ok
```

#### Update

This is me running a `psql` query after running precisely the code you've shown above on a string (varchar) field:

```
testdb=# select error_data from tt;
                                  error_data                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"message":"Invalid token","cause":[],"error":"not_found","status":401}
(1 row)
```

Comment: I see it from the DB query (SELECT * FROM error_table). I have inserted a plain not-escaped content aside, so both show up on the query result. The one from my test is OK. I can't manage to attach an /mage here, otherwise I could show it.

Comment: You'll need to show us what you're seeing.  I just updated my answer showing the result of running precisely the code you've got for a new string field on a new table I created.  So, there's some details you're not explaining/showing.